# JavaScript variable not getting the value of an id by getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Here's the html:

```
<form>
      <input type="text" id="text1" required>
      <button type="submit" onclick="checkBen()">Add</button>
      <small id="beneficialAlear"></small>
 </form>
```

And the javaScript:

```
function checkBen(){
            var str = document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML.value;
            if(str != null){
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("beneficialAlear").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };

                alert(str);
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "../getFromAJAX.php?q=benUsername&str=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
```

The variable **str** gets null even if I input something and thus the never goes to the ajax. :(
Is there a problem in the code or something? Anykind of help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `innerHTML` is a string.  Strings have no `value` property.

Comment: It should be `var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;`.

Comment: Leave out `.innerHTML`: `document.getElementById("text1").value;`

Comment: thank you... leaving the .innerHTML out solved it :)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be saying `document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML.value;` as the element has no `innerHTML`. You want `document.getElementById('text1').value`.

E.G.:

```js
function checkBen() {
    var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    // ... your code ..., E.G.:
    alert(str);
}
```

```html
<form>
      <input type="text" id="text1" required>
      <button type="submit" onclick="checkBen()">Add</button>
      <small id="beneficialAlear"></small>
 </form>
```

Comment: This was answered several times in the comments. There's no need for them to be duplicated in a full answer.